# Getting error while executing the query?

Tags: sql, ado.net

When I run my query:

```
UPDATE oms.Document_Latest 
SET size ='54324', CheckInBy = 'Anshul123', 
    Status ='checkedin', CheckOutBy = 'NULL', 
    CheckInOn = '4/28/2016 1:45:36 PM', CheckOutOn = 'NULL' 
WHERE (Id = '1')
```

[image]

Datatype of columns are given in image which is attached with this question

I get this error:

> Msg 241, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

Please help me find the reason why I get this error while execute this query.

Thanks

Comment: Why the quotes around NULL? Are you trying to insert a character string value?

Answer (score 6):

You receive an error that because you trying to update `CheckOutOn` column of datatype `DATETIME` with string `'NULL'`. You have to remove quotes `''` from `NULL` in following:

```
UPDATE oms.Document_Latest 
SET size ='54324', 
    CheckInBy = 'Anshul123', 
    Status ='checkedin', 
    CheckOutBy = NULL, 
    CheckInOn = '4/28/2016 1:45:36 PM', 
    CheckOutOn = NULL 
WHERE (Id = '1')
```

Comment: I'm not sure in this case, but isn't `NULL` by default an `INT`? Don't you have to `cast` it to the correct type?

Comment: @HoneyBadger I'm not sure what exactly you're talking about, but seems that this was issue why OP received that error. In this case no need any convertings.

Comment: @HoneyBadger: `NULL` is just "no value" - it doesn't have any datatype associated with it.

Comment: @marc_s, Thanks, I know what `NULL` is, I just remember I sometimes had problems with the datatype of a `select null` kind of thing. But I can't remember the exact circumstance anymore.

Comment: @AparnaSingh do not forget to accept It as correct answer If It helped for you. To do It you can check `V` in top-left of an answer.